# Pprof and golang - how to interpret a results?

Tags: linux, go, pprof

I am trying to use pprof on my program, however, I have slightly different results from articles I read (links below). In my results, I am getting such table:

```
(pprof) top10
1.65s of 1.72s total (95.93%)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 114 (cum >= 0.01s)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
     1.19s 69.19% 69.19%      1.20s 69.77%  syscall.Syscall
     0.16s  9.30% 78.49%      0.16s  9.30%  runtime._ExternalCode
```

what are this columns: `flat flat% sum% cum cum%`?

Articles I was reading: 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/05/10/debugging-performance-issues-in-go-programs
http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: The format is a little different, but the data and columns still have the same meaning. 'flat' is the time in a function, 'cum' is the cumulative time is a function and everything below it.

Comment: Do you mind to change your title to `What does flat, flat%, sum%, cum, cum% mean in Golang pprof results?`

Comment: I think it maybe easier to reach when people search this kind of question.

Answer (score 43):

### flat and cum

Assuming there is a function foo, which is composed of 3 functions and a direct operation.

```
func foo(){
    a()                                 step1
    b()                                 step2
    do something directly.              step3
    c()                                 step4
}
```

Imagine when you call function `foo`, it takes 6 seconds, and the time distribution are following.

```
func foo(){
    a()                                 // step1 takes 1s
    b()                                 // step2 takes 1s
    do something directly.              // step3 takes 3s
    c()                                 // step4 takes 1s
}
```

- `flat` would be the time spent on step3.
- `cum` would be the total execution time of foo, which contains sub-function call and direct operations. (cum = step1+ step2+ step3+ step4)

### sum%

when you run `top` in pprof console, each line of output stands for the time spent on specific function. `Sum%` means how much time/memory has been spent by previous lines.

To explain this metric, I pick another example which contains more lines. the value of `sum%` for forth line is 45.17%. it's the calculated in this way:

```
line1 19.33%
line2 13.27%
line3 6.60%
line4 5.97%
-----------
sum% 45.17%
```

[image]

### Application of sum%

`sum%` could help you to identify the big rocks quickly. The following is another example of memory allocation report.

You can see that the first four functions consume 91.06% memory. If I want to do some performance tuning, I should focus on first four functions. All the functions below fourth could be ignored.

[image]

### Reference

[Reddit: What is the meaning of "flat" and "cum" in golang pprof output](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/7ony5f/what_is_the_meaning_of_flat_and_cum_in_golang/)

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm going to get flack for this, but take a look at the GopherCon talks; [one such example on interpretation is here](http://www.gophercon.in/2016/pdf/gcon1.pdf), there is also a talk from [Uber about pprof](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1n6bse0JifemG7yve0Bb0ZAC-IWhTQjCNAclblnn2ANY) as well.

There is also [Profiling Go Programs](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) blog post.